# Simple Ajax Request Without Component/Module/Plugin

Tags: ajax, com-ajax

I am trying to create a simple login popup. From the shared image of UI, you can see, a login button(top right) which opens a popup for login form.

https://prnt.sc/1mc5ppq

Now, I want to pass the email and password to the backend and get it verified. I used axios with POST request.

How should be the target URL specified and in which file should I create the php function to verify the username and password.

Do I need to create a dummy component or module or plugin to achieve this.

Googling I saw some urls were

```
index.php?com_ajax&task=loginVerify
```

But not sure where to write this function loginVerify

Comment: Simplest way is to make a module and write your loginVerify method in the module helper. https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

Comment: I got that. But i need to create a plugin for that. Just want to confirm

Comment: If by "plugin" you mean extension, then yes. You will need to create a module.